# How to convert a JSON string into a JSON arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, object

I have a String and i want to show it in list so i have to convert it in Array list
How can i do this?
I have tried these things

```
     String Result =response.body().getGetFlightAvailibilityResponse().getGetFlightAvailibilityResult().getGetFlightAvailibilityResponse().getFlightDetails();
                    try {




                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Object>>() 
                        {}.getType();
                        List<String> contactList = gson.fromJson(Result, 
                        type);


                      //  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Result);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

This is my String

> [[SrNo,AirlineCode,FlightNo,FromAirportCode,ToAirportCode,DepDate,DepTime,ArrDate,ArrTime,FlightClass,FlightTime,TotalAmount,TaxAmount,Stops,ValCarrier,FromTerminal,ToTerminal,MainClass,FareBasis,AgencyCharge,FareType,AvailSeats,FlightRemarks,TrackNo],[100YO,9W,346,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:30,04/10/2018,09:40,O,130,3998,1798,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|100YO],[101YO,9W,953,BOM,JAI,04/10/2018,14:35,04/10/2018,16:30,O,115,4550,1949,1,9W,2,
>   2,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|101YO],[101YO,9W,788,JAI,DEL,04/10/2018,17:00,04/10/2018,18:05,O,65,0,0,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|101YO],[102YO,9W,2418,BOM,JAI,04/10/2018,18:20,04/10/2018,20:10,O,110,4550,1949,1,9W,2,
>   2,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|102YO],[102YO,9W,756,JAI,DEL,04/10/2018,21:15,04/10/2018,22:20,O,65,0,0,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|102YO],[103YO,9W,309,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,19:00,04/10/2018,21:15,V,135,4995,1845,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|103YO],[104YO,9W,2374,BOM,LKO,04/10/2018,12:25,04/10/2018,14:45,W,140,5053,2573,1,9W,2,
>   2,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|104YO],[104YO,9W,856,LKO,DEL,04/10/2018,15:40,04/10/2018,17:00,W,80,0,0,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|104YO],[105YO,9W,2929,BOM,AMD,04/10/2018,02:50,04/10/2018,04:00,H,70,5315,1985,1,9W,2,
>   1,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|105YO],[105YO,9W,685,AMD,DEL,04/10/2018,05:35,04/10/2018,07:20,H,105,0,0,0,9W,1,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|105YO],[106YO,9W,385,BOM,IDR,04/10/2018,17:35,04/10/2018,18:55,V,80,6229,2029,1,9W,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|106YO],[106YO,9W,794,IDR,DEL,04/10/2018,20:20,04/10/2018,22:50,V,150,0,0,0,9W,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|106YO],[107YO,9W,2377,BOM,RPR,04/10/2018,06:35,04/10/2018,08:30,V,115,6329,2034,1,9W,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|107YO],[107YO,9W,2735,RPR,DEL,04/10/2018,09:00,04/10/2018,10:50,V,110,0,0,0,9W,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|107YO],[108YO,9W,895,BOM,BHO,04/10/2018,18:40,04/10/2018,20:10,V,90,6743,2053,1,9W,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|108YO],[108YO,9W,928,BHO,DEL,04/10/2018,21:00,04/10/2018,22:25,V,85,0,0,0,9W,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|108YO],[109YO,9W,2967,BOM,RPR,04/10/2018,17:25,04/10/2018,19:25,V,120,7016,2066,1,9W,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|109YO],[109YO,9W,2677,RPR,DEL,04/10/2018,20:05,04/10/2018,21:55,V,110,0,0,0,9W,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|109YO],[10YO,SG,153,BOM,COK,04/10/2018,09:30,04/10/2018,11:30,C,120,7334,725,1,SG,1,
>   1,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|10YO],[10YO,SG,184,COK,DEL,04/10/2018,13:45,04/10/2018,18:00,C,255,0,0,1,SG,1,,Y,,0,R,0,,0$307|37|10YO],[110YO,9W,413,BOM,BLR,04/10/2018,16:30,04/10/2018,18:15,H,105,7724,2959,1,9W,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|110YO],[110YO,9W,833,BLR,DEL,04/10/2018,18:55,04/10/2018,21:50,H,175,0,0,0,9W,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|110YO],[111YO,9W,703,BOM,DED,04/10/2018,11:00,04/10/2018,13:15,K,135,11531,2881,1,9W,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|111YO],[111YO,9W,150,DED,DEL,04/10/2018,13:50,04/10/2018,15:10,K,80,0,0,0,9W,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|111YO],[112YO,9W,701,BOM,DED,04/10/2018,13:05,04/10/2018,15:20,M,135,36278,4060,1,9W,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|112YO],[112YO,9W,186,DED,DEL,04/10/2018,17:10,04/10/2018,18:20,M,70,0,0,0,9W,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|112YO],[11YO,SG,153,BOM,COK,04/10/2018,09:30,04/10/2018,11:30,C,120,9854,1245,1,SG,1,
>   1,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|11YO],[11YO,SG,184,COK,DEL,04/10/2018,13:45,04/10/2018,18:00,C,255,0,0,1,SG,1,,Y,,0,R,0,,0$307|37|11YO],[12YO,SG,153,BOM,COK,04/10/2018,09:30,04/10/2018,11:30,E,120,10274,1265,1,SG,1,
>   1,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|12YO],[12YO,SG,184,COK,DEL,04/10/2018,13:45,04/10/2018,18:00,C,255,0,0,1,SG,1,,Y,,0,R,0,,0$307|37|12YO],[13YO,AI,217,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,10:25,04/10/2018,11:45,S,80,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|13YO],[14YO,AI,61,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|14YO],[15YO,AI,66,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|15YO],[16YO,AI,67,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|16YO],[17YO,AI,107,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|17YO],[18YO,AI,212,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|18YO],[19YO,AI,323,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|19YO],[1YO,SG,160,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,07:55,H,115,2811,711,0,SG,1,
>   1C,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|1YO],[20YO,AI,326,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|20YO],[21YO,AI,455,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|21YO],[22YO,AI,523,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|22YO],[23YO,AI,752,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|23YO],[24YO,AI,789,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|24YO],[25YO,AI,801,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|25YO],[26YO,AI,802,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|26YO],[27YO,AI,1111,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,02:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|27YO],[28YO,AI,300,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,03:00,04/10/2018,04:30,S,90,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|28YO],[29YO,AI,256,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,00:10,04/10/2018,01:45,S,95,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|29YO],[2YO,SG,160,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,07:55,C,115,3021,521,0,SG,1,
>   1C,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|2YO],[30YO,AI,257,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,00:10,04/10/2018,01:45,S,95,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|30YO],[31YO,AI,5011,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,00:10,04/10/2018,02:10,S,120,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|31YO],[32YO,AI,97,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:00,S,120,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|32YO],[33YO,AI,98,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:00,S,120,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|33YO],[34YO,AI,99,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:00,S,120,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|34YO],[35YO,AI,4141,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,10:00,04/10/2018,12:00,S,120,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|35YO],[36YO,AI,3,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,12:00,04/10/2018,14:00,S,120,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|36YO],[37YO,AI,864,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:00,04/10/2018,09:05,S,125,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|37YO],[38YO,AI,144,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,17:00,04/10/2018,19:10,S,130,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|38YO],[39YO,AI,101,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,21:00,04/10/2018,23:10,S,130,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|39YO],[3YO,SG,152,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:20,04/10/2018,09:35,H,135,2811,711,0,SG,1,
>   1C,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|3YO],[40YO,AI,200,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,21:00,04/10/2018,23:10,S,130,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|40YO],[41YO,AI,232,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,05:15,04/10/2018,07:30,S,135,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|41YO],[42YO,AI,348,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:55,04/10/2018,10:10,S,135,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|42YO],[43YO,AI,806,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,08:00,04/10/2018,10:15,S,135,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|43YO],[44YO,AI,809,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,10:00,04/10/2018,12:15,S,135,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|44YO],[45YO,AI,677,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,13:00,04/10/2018,15:15,S,135,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|45YO],[46YO,AI,687,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,16:00,04/10/2018,18:15,S,135,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|46YO],[47YO,AI,310,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,19:45,04/10/2018,22:00,S,135,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|47YO],[48YO,AI,866,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,09:00,04/10/2018,11:25,S,145,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|48YO],[49YO,AI,660,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,18:00,04/10/2018,20:25,S,145,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|49YO],[4YO,SG,152,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:20,04/10/2018,09:35,C,135,3021,521,0,SG,1,
>   1C,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|4YO],[50YO,AI,555,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,03:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|50YO],[51YO,AI,666,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,03:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|51YO],[52YO,AI,2123,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,03:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|52YO],[53YO,AI,150,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,05:00,04/10/2018,07:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|53YO],[54YO,AI,100,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:00,04/10/2018,09:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|54YO],[55YO,AI,85,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,12:00,04/10/2018,14:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|55YO],[56YO,AI,5190,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,21:00,04/10/2018,23:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|56YO],[57YO,AI,5191,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,21:00,04/10/2018,23:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|57YO],[58YO,AI,250,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,04:00,S,180,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|58YO],[59YO,AI,2323,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,04:00,S,180,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|59YO],[5YO,SG,158,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,18:45,04/10/2018,20:55,H,130,2811,711,0,SG,1,
>   1C,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|5YO],[60YO,AI,5578,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,20:00,04/10/2018,23:00,S,180,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|60YO],[61YO,AI,5580,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,20:00,04/10/2018,23:00,S,180,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|61YO],[62YO,AI,413,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,20:15,04/10/2018,23:30,S,195,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|62YO],[63YO,AI,423,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,20:15,04/10/2018,23:30,S,195,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|63YO],[64YO,AI,777,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,20:15,04/10/2018,23:30,S,195,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|64YO],[65YO,AI,1066,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,20:15,04/10/2018,23:30,S,195,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|65YO],[66YO,AI,635,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:05,04/10/2018,11:10,S,245,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|66YO],[67YO,AI,7019,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:00,S,120,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|67YO],[68YO,AI,6293,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,21:00,04/10/2018,23:30,S,150,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|68YO],[69YO,AI,9823,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,04:30,S,210,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|69YO],[6YO,SG,158,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,18:45,04/10/2018,20:55,C,130,3021,521,0,SG,1,
>   1C,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|6YO],[70YO,AI,9897,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,04:30,S,210,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|70YO],[71YO,AI,9824,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,01:00,04/10/2018,05:00,S,240,4255,555,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|71YO],[72YO,AI,888,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,19:00,04/10/2018,21:15,S,135,4255,555,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|72YO],[73YO,AI,442,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,15:25,04/10/2018,19:10,K,225,12865,965,0,AI,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|73YO],[74YO,AI,621,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,00:20,04/10/2018,02:00,M,100,19532,1282,0,AI,2,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|74YO],[75YO,AI,4012,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:00,M,120,19532,1282,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|75YO],[76YO,AI,4015,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:00,M,120,19532,1282,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|76YO],[77YO,AI,4017,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:00,M,120,19532,1282,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|77YO],[78YO,AI,5353,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:00,M,120,19532,1282,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|78YO],[79YO,AI,3131,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,12:00,04/10/2018,14:00,M,120,19532,1282,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|79YO],[7YO,SG,154,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,21:30,04/10/2018,23:50,H,140,2811,711,0,SG,1,
>   1C,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|7YO],[80YO,AI,8899,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:30,04/10/2018,09:30,M,120,19532,1282,0,AI,,,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|80YO],[81YO,9W,361,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,20:45,04/10/2018,22:55,B,130,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|81YO],[82YO,9W,762,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,06:00,04/10/2018,08:15,B,135,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|82YO],[83YO,9W,301,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,07:00,04/10/2018,09:15,B,135,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|83YO],[84YO,9W,355,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,08:30,04/10/2018,10:45,B,135,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|84YO],[85YO,9W,333,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,08:00,04/10/2018,10:20,B,140,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|85YO],[86YO,9W,331,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,10:00,04/10/2018,12:20,B,140,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|86YO],[87YO,9W,311,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,18:00,04/10/2018,20:20,B,140,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|87YO],[88YO,9W,839,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,09:00,04/10/2018,11:25,B,145,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|88YO],[89YO,9W,307,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,11:00,04/10/2018,13:20,B,140,2549,1729,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|89YO],[8YO,SG,154,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,21:30,04/10/2018,23:50,C,140,3021,521,0,SG,1,
>   1C,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|8YO],[90YO,9W,351,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,14:00,04/10/2018,16:10,B,130,2633,1733,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|90YO],[91YO,9W,310,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,22:35,05/10/2018,00:45,B,130,2633,1733,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|91YO],[92YO,9W,329,BOM,AMD,04/10/2018,05:20,04/10/2018,06:30,B,70,2642,1858,1,9W,2,
>   1,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|92YO],[92YO,9W,687,AMD,DEL,04/10/2018,07:00,04/10/2018,08:40,B,100,0,0,0,9W,1,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|92YO],[93YO,9W,353,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,17:00,04/10/2018,19:15,W,135,3200,1760,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|93YO],[94YO,9W,2929,BOM,AMD,04/10/2018,02:50,04/10/2018,04:00,W,70,3373,1893,1,9W,2,
>   1,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|94YO],[94YO,9W,687,AMD,DEL,04/10/2018,07:00,04/10/2018,08:40,W,100,0,0,0,9W,1,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|94YO],[95YO,9W,914,BOM,AMD,04/10/2018,16:55,04/10/2018,18:15,W,80,3373,1893,1,9W,2,
>   1,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|95YO],[95YO,9W,687,AMD,DEL,05/10/2018,07:00,05/10/2018,08:40,W,100,0,0,0,9W,1,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|95YO],[96YO,9W,914,BOM,AMD,04/10/2018,16:55,04/10/2018,18:15,W,80,3373,1893,1,9W,2,
>   1,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|96YO],[96YO,9W,655,AMD,DEL,05/10/2018,15:10,05/10/2018,16:50,W,100,0,0,0,9W,1,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|96YO],[97YO,9W,637,BOM,AMD,04/10/2018,21:45,04/10/2018,23:05,W,80,3641,1906,1,9W,2,
>   1,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|97YO],[97YO,9W,687,AMD,DEL,05/10/2018,07:00,05/10/2018,08:40,W,100,0,0,0,9W,1,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|97YO],[98YO,9W,637,BOM,AMD,04/10/2018,21:45,04/10/2018,23:05,W,80,3641,1906,1,9W,2,
>   1,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|98YO],[98YO,9W,655,AMD,DEL,05/10/2018,15:10,05/10/2018,16:50,W,100,0,0,0,9W,1,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|98YO],[99YO,9W,339,BOM,DEL,04/10/2018,03:00,04/10/2018,05:05,O,125,3998,1798,0,9W,2,
>   3,Y,,0,N,0,,0$307|37|99YO],[9YO,SG,153,BOM,COK,04/10/2018,09:30,04/10/2018,11:30,H,120,3021,921,1,SG,1,
>   1,Y,,500,R,0,,0$307|37|9YO],[9YO,SG,184,COK,DEL,04/10/2018,13:45,04/10/2018,18:00,H,255,0,0,1,SG,1,,Y,,0,R,0,,0$307|37|9YO]]

Comment: you can see my string is diffrent

Comment: doesn't matter. you can use that method to convert your string

Comment: i have already used but it throwing unterminated array at charcter of 277

Comment: anyway thanks for your reply

Comment: Your question is unclear. In your code you are creating `TypeToken` for `<List<Object>>` but later you are using `List<String>`. Also your list contains lists of strings, not JSONobjects, nor strings. Maybe try with `TypeToken<List<List<String>>>` and make sure you each `[` has its closing `]`

Comment: Invalid json , use proper json

Comment: thanks Pshemo let me try this

Comment: Also in proper JSON Strings are wrapped in `'` or `"`. Are you in charge of creating that JSON? If yes make sure that those quotes are added, if not try to contact JSON provider and ask for that change.

Comment: throwing unterminated array at charcter of 277 not sure whats wrong on this character

Comment: It looks like gson complains about `/` which isn't part of any JSON syntax. You wouldn't face that problem if each string data would be properly wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are getting JSONObject so you can convert it on

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readlocationFeed); 

line with following

JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(readlocationFeed);

and after

JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("locations");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

This object you can add on Arraylist.

Comment: no i am getting jsonarray you can see my string

Answer (score -2):

```
This will help you.


JSONArray jsonArrayList = new JSONArray(); 

ArrayList<String> label=new ArrayList<>();

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readlocationFeed); 
if(jsonArray.length()>0){

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                JSONArray jsonArrayForValue = new JSONArray(jsonArray.get(i)); 



                if(i==0){

                ////////**********For Label/Header*******///////////

                        for(int j=0;j<jsonArrayForValue.length();j++){

                                label.add(jsonArrayForValue.get(j));
                        }

                }else{

                    JSONObject eachDeatail=new JSONObject();
                    for(int j=0;j<jsonArrayForValue.length();j++){


                        eachDeatail.put(label.get(j),jsonArrayForValue.get(label.get(j)).toString());

                        }   

                        jsonArrayList.add(eachDeatail);
                }

        }
}
```

Comment: it throwing error in this line JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readlocationFeed);

Comment: unterminated array at charcter of 277 this is the error thanks for your reply

Comment: please send me the image of errors.In which line of code you got error ?